# Pass a byte array to oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I have one problem with passing byte array into Oracle stored procedure as input parameter using odp.net.

Here is stored procedure signature:

```
SOMEPROCEDURE(session IN NUMBER, data IN RAW)
```

Here is C# code, which call procedure:

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("SOME_PROCEDURE", _connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var bt = new byte[]{1,68,0,83,128,1};
OracleParameter sessionId = new OracleParameter("dbSessionId", OracleDbType.Decimal, new OracleDecimal(_dbSessionId), ParameterDirection.Input);                
OracleParameter data = new OracleParameter("statusData", OracleDbType.Raw, new OracleBinary(bt), ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.Parameters.Add(sessionId);
cmd.Parameters.Add(data);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code fails(stored procedure throws exception, that can't get data), because in byte array thereis number 128!, if I chage 128 on another number,less 128, it works fine!

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("SOME_PROCEDURE", _connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
int[] bt = new int[]{1,68,0,83,128,1};
OracleParameter sessionId = new OracleParameter("dbSessionId", OracleDbType.Decimal, new OracleDecimal(_dbSessionId), ParameterDirection.Input);                
OracleParameter data = new OracleParameter("statusData", OracleDbType.Raw, new OracleBinary(bt), ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.Parameters.Add(sessionId);
cmd.Parameters.Add(data);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this is probably because a byte is to small, an int might work because it could contain a bigger number.

Comment: There is no `OracleBinary` constructor takes `Int32` array as a parameter and there is no implicit conversation from `byte` array to `int` array.

Comment: I did not know that, you could try to make 2 arrays of byte's than.

Comment: byte is not small, byte is 8 bit unsigned integer, so its max value is 255. It seems, that oracle data row couln't contains from unsigned 8 bit values.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I have found solution.
At first, You can't pass to stored procedure array of bytes via odp.net, if this array contains values great than 127.

So, solution:
1. Create wrapper procedure

```
procedure SOME_PROCEDURE_WRAPPER (p_session_id in number,
                                  p_data       in varchar2)
is
 v_data  raw(1024);
 rawdata  raw(1024);
 rawlen number;
 hex varchar2(32760);
 i number;    
 begin  

  rawlen := length(p_data);
  i := 1;
  while i <= rawlen-1 
  loop
     hex := substrb(p_data,i,2);
     rawdata := rawdata || HEXTORAW(hex);
     i := i + 2;
  end loop;  
  SOME_PROCEDURE(p_session_id , rawdata);
 end;
```

2 Then need to modify C# code in this way:

```
 var cmd = new OracleCommand("SOME_PROCEDURE_WRAPPER", _connection);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 string @string = statusData.ToHexString();
 OracleParameter sessionId = new OracleParameter("dbSessionId", OracleDbType.Decimal, new OracleDecimal(_dbSessionId), ParameterDirection.Input);                
 OracleParameter data = new OracleParameter("statusData", OracleDbType.Varchar2,@string.Length, new OracleString(@string), ParameterDirection.Input);
 cmd.Parameters.Add(sessionId);
 cmd.Parameters.Add(data);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

where

```
public static string ToHexString(this byte[] bytes)
    { 
        if(bytes == null || bytes.Length == null)
            return string.Empty;
        StringBuilder hexStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte @byte in bytes)
        {
            hexStringBuilder.Append(@byte.ToString("X2"));
        }
        return hexStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```